# Regex - how to make sure a string contain a word and numbers

Tags: regex

I need a little help with Regex.
I want the regex to validate the following sentences:

```
fdsufgdsugfugh PCL 6
dfdagf PCL 11
fdsfds PCL6
fsfs PCL13
kl;klkPCL6
fdsgfdsPCL13
```

some chars, than PCL and than 6 or a greater number.
How this can be done?

Comment: please post expcted result what you want to do with filtered data

Comment: are `some chars` necessarly before `PCL` or can these be after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with something like this:
`^(.*)(PCL *)([6-9][0-9]*|[1-5][0-9]+)$`

Meaning:

- `(.*)` = some chars
- `(PCL *)` = then PCL with optional whitespaces afterwards
- `([6-9][0-9]*|[1-5][0-9]+)` then 6 or a greater number

Answer (score 0):

In `bash`:

`EXPR=^[a-zA-Z]\+ *PCL *\([6-9]\|[0-9]\{2,\}\)`

Translated:

- Line begins with at least 1 occurence of a character (ignore caps)
- Any amount of spaces, PCL, any amount of spaces
- Either a number between 6 or 9, or a number with at least 2 digits

This expression used with something like `grep "$EXPR" file.txt` will output in stdout the lines that are valid.

Answer (score 0):

This one should suit your needs:

```
^.*PCL\s*(?:[6-9]|\d{2,})$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Visualization by [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Nl2LvxEnPMq2-feQ)

Answer (score 0):

This worked well for me.  Reads logically too according to the way you described the matching

`/[^PCL]+PCL\s?*[6-9]\d*/`